# PERMANOVA to calculate cytokine variation explained by species composition

Tags: vegan, pcoa, permanova

I am trying to calculate the cytokine variation explained by species composition within my data set based on figure 2D in the following paper (Schirmer, M., Smeekens, S.P., Vlamakis, H., Jaeger, M., Oosting, M., Franzosa, E.A., Ter Horst, R., Jansen, T., Jacobs, L., Bonder, M.J. and Kurilshikov, A., 2016. Linking the human gut microbiome to inflammatory cytokine production capacity. Cell, 167(4), pp.1125-1136), with the image and text available within the publication in the photo at the bottom of the post.

What I want to make sure I tackle correctly is the PERMANOVA setup. I have performed PCoA to represent the microbiota to avoid overestimation due to species-species correlations.

My data consists of 11 different cytokine markers and 16S amplicon data for 8 patients collected before, during, and after antibiotic treatment.

If someone could please help me determine the best way to approach the PERMANOVA formula, or formulas, to calculate the cytokine variation explained by species composition, I would be very appreciative! For reference, I usually do my PERMANOVA tests using the vegan package within R, and would like to stick with R as it is what I use the most.

Thank you!
[image]